# Using TikZ in tablular for drawing intervals

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

How can I draw table like this (with interval diagrams) using TikZ?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick try:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,array}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathmorphing}

\newcommand{\Interval}[4]{%
    \tikz{%
        \coordinate [label={center:$#1$},label=below:$\rule{0pt}{.35cm}#2$] (a) at (0,0); 
        \coordinate [label={center:$#3$},label=below:$\rule{0pt}{.35cm}#4$] (b) at (1.6,0); 
        \draw[-{latex},] decorate[decoration=zigzag] {(a)--(b)} (-.4,0)--(2,0);
    }
}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\insertinterval}[1]{\rule{0in}{.7cm}\parbox{2.5cm}{#1}}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline
\insertinterval{\Interval{[}{a}{]}{b}} & $ ? < x < ? $ & $? a , b?$ \\ \hline
\insertinterval{\Interval{[}{a}{]}{b}} & $ ? < x < ? $ & $? a , b?$ \\ \hline
\insertinterval{\Interval{]}{a}{[}{b}} & $ ? < x < ? $ & $? a , b?$ \\ \hline
\insertinterval{\Interval{]}{a}{[}{b}} & $ ? < x < ? $ & $? a , b?$ \\ \hline
\insertinterval{\Interval{ }{ }{ }{ }} & $ ? < x < ? $ & $? a , b?$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

We define a `\newcommand` named `\Interval` which takes in four arguments as this:

```
\newcommand{\Interval}[4]{%
        \tikz{%
            \coordinate [label={center:$#1$},label=below:$\rule{0pt}{.35cm}#2$] (a) at (0,0); 
            \coordinate [label={center:$#3$},label=below:$\rule{0pt}{.35cm}#4$] (b) at (1.6,0); 
            \draw[-{latex},] decorate[decoration=zigzag] {(a)--(b)} (-.4,0)--(2,0);
    }
  }
```

and recall it wherever needed in the table.